# How to pass user to named route with a stateful widget using Navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

#### My Setup

- Login Route - asynchronously checks if a user is logged
- Checkin Route - Consists of a main stateful widget and several stateless children widgets that depend on the information of the logged in user

#### My Idea

- After the user login is identified on the login route, use Navigator to pass along the user object to the checkin route
- children widgets can receive the user object through their constructor

#### My Problem

- the user object is not 'arriving' in the stateful widget of the checkin route

#### Files

Here are the relevant code snippets to check (I added them from more complex files and hope I got all imports correct):

*Main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginView.dart';
import 'checkinView.dart';

void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                '/': (BuildContext context) => LoginView(),
                '/checkin': (BuildContext context) => CheckinView(),
            }
        );
    }
}
```

*LoginView.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    LoginViewState createState() => LoginViewState();
}

class LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        checkLoginAndRedirect();
    }

    void checkLoginAndRedirect() async {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser currUser){
            if(currUser != null){
                print("[LoginView - user] $currUser");
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/checkin', arguments: {currUser});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*CheckinView.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'checkinList.dart';

class CheckinView extends StatefulWidget {
    final FirebaseUser user;

    CheckinView({this.user});

    @override
    CheckinViewState createState() {
        print("[CheckinView - user] $user");
        return CheckinViewState();
    }
}

class CheckinViewState extends State<CheckinView> {
    FirebaseUser _currentUser;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        setState((){
            _currentUser = widget.user;
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        print("[CheckinViewState - widget.user] " + widget.user.toString());

        return Scaffold(
            body: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    CheckinList(user: _currentUser)
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

*CheckinList.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class CheckinList extends StatelessWidget{
    FirebaseUser user = null;

    CheckinList({this.user = null});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Text(user['name'])
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262655/flutter-get-passed-arguments-from-navigator-in-widgets-states-initstate. I had the same problem.  This answer worked.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

- The arguments need extraction in the build method of the WidgetState (because only there we have the BuildContext)
- Navigator is automagically handling the arguments correct, even with Stateful Widgets - THANKS FLUTTER TEAM!!!!

#### My adapted Files

*Main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginView.dart';
import 'checkinView.dart';

void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                '/': (BuildContext context) => LoginView(),
                '/checkin': (BuildContext context) => CheckinView(),
            }
        );
    }
}
```

*LoginView.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    LoginViewState createState() => LoginViewState();
}

class LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        checkLoginAndRedirect();
    }

    void checkLoginAndRedirect() async {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser currUser){
            if(currUser != null){
                print("[LoginView - user] $currUser");
                //// pass a map as 'arguments' to be ready to pass along more variables in the future
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/checkin', arguments: {'user': currUser});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*CheckinView.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'checkinList.dart';

class CheckinView extends StatefulWidget {
    //// leave the stateful class as usual

    @override
    CheckinViewState createState() => CheckinViewState();
}

class CheckinViewState extends State<CheckinView> {
    //// don't bother in the initState method as the BuildContext is missing here

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        //// access the passed arguments
        Map<String, dynamic> args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

        print("[CheckinViewState - widget.user] " + widget.user.toString());

        return Scaffold(
            body: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    //// access the passed variables through 'args'
                    CheckinList(user: args.user)
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

*CheckinList.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class CheckinList extends StatelessWidget{
    FirebaseUser user = null;

    //// assign the user in your constructor
    CheckinList(FirebaseUser user){
        this.user = user;
    };

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Text(user['name'])
        );
    }
}
```

Read more in the cookbook about it:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#create-a-detail-screen-to-extract-the-arguments
- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can try it. I hope it can help you

```
class LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        checkLoginAndRedirect();
    }

    void checkLoginAndRedirect() async {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser currUser){
            if(currUser != null){
                print("[LoginView - user] $currUser");
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/checkin', arguments: currUser); /// <--- fixed here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
class CheckinView extends StatefulWidget {
    RouteSettings settings = ModalRoute.of(context).settings /// <--- fixed here
    FirebaseUser user = settings.arguments; /// <--- fixed here

    @override
    CheckinViewState createState() {
        print("[CheckinView - user] $user");
        return CheckinViewState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access passed data using `ModalRoute` inside `build` method, below code will give you can idea how to do it,

```
class LevelViewChildScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  UserModel user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    user = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return LevelViewChild(user);
  }
}

class LevelViewChild extends StatefulWidget {
  UserModel user;

  LevelViewChild(this.user);
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I see where you're coming from (the cookbook) actually, it is even much simpler .. I will add the answer below ...

Comment: Yeah, I already know you can pass a map or list, although I was just trying to help.