# Flutter: How to pass parameter to FutureBuilder future instance?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

For prevent rebuild, I use a future instance `_futureInstance` in `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
var _futureInstance;

Future _loadData() async {
    // ...
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureInstance = _loadData();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureInstance,
        // ...
    )
}
```

It works well, now if the `_loadData` method has a parameter, such as `_loadData(int i)`, how can I pass the parameter `i` to `_futureInstance`?

Comment: if it has a parameter, that should cause a rebuild right?? if it is one time parameter whats wrong in passing it in the initState??

Comment: To Yadu: this parameter is passed from prev. page.

Comment: Your question was not clear, there exists many answers to pass arguments to route

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in another way, use `MaterialApp.onGenerateRoute`.

As this answer: [Flutter: Get passed arguments from Navigator in Widget's state's initState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262655/flutter-get-passed-arguments-from-navigator-in-widgets-states-initstate/56280046#56280046)

I get the parameter in `initState` method:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureInstance = _loadData(widget.parameter_key);
    // ...
```

and in `build`, the code not change:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureInstance,
        // ...
    )
}
```

In this way, the method `_loadData` can use various parameters, and the widget is not rebuild when `setState` is called.

Answer (score -1):

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureInstance = (int i) => _loadData(i);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureInstance(1), // pass your number here
        // ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, in the way I can pass the parameter, but each time `setState` called, the widget rebuiled and the `_loadData` is recalled...

Answer (score -1):

wasn't sure the purpose of _futureInstance, perhaps you don't need to define the instance?

```
Future _loadData(val) async {
    // ...
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadData(1),
        // ...
    )
}
```

Comment: The OP already explained why this is exactly what they don't want on a different answer.

Comment: i think i missed that very first line, which instead OP should be using streambuilder instead of futurebuilder. FutureBuilder don't mean to be rebuild but streambuilder does.

Comment: You still misunderstand. "Yes, in the way I can pass the parameter, but each time setState called, the widget rebuiled and the _loadData is recalled." When `setState` is called, `_loadData` will be recalled which is undesirable behavior.

Answer (score -1):

i would approach like this

```
var _lastInt = 0;
var _lastFuture;


Future _loadData(int i) async {
  if(_lastInt!=i||_lastFuture==null){
    //do work
    _lastInt = i;
    _lastFuture = ;
  }
  return _lastFuture;
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: _loadData(1),
    // ...
  );
```

Comment: The OP already explained why this is exactly what they don't want on **two** different answer.